# How to add JSON object into JSON array using angular JS?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have problem while parsing single json object.

Assume that the below data get from server

```
        {
            "root": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Raj",
                        "age": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Janu",
                        "age": "22"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

And my script is

Script.js

```
        var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
           $http.get("manydata.json")
            .success(function(response) {
              $scope.myDatas = response.root;
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-repeat="i in myDatas.data">

          Name: {{i.name}}
          Age: {{i.age}}

     </div>
```

I have no problem while the response data is more than 1. But If the response data is 1 then the json will be:

```
    {
      "root": {
        "data": {
          "name": "Raj",
          "age": "22"
        }
      }
    }
```

How to generically parse these json data ?

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/W4YK6BDtIBfVhnPpHVm1?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried fixing this on the server side? For example you can return an empty array in case of no data, that should be parsed just fine through the HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just slight change, check type of `responsedata.root.data`. If it is not array, convert it to array. Here is your code becomes.
Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yRzXC6z8WYpfVGnZT08o?p=preview)

```
// Code goes here

var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
   $http.get("singledata.json")
    .success(function(response) {
      if(response.root.data && !(response.root.data instanceof Array )){
        response.root.data=[response.root.data]
      } 

      $scope.myDatas = response.root;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can normalize incoming data to always be an array. It's convenient to use [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method for this:

```
$http.get("singledata.json")
.success(function(response) {
  $scope.myDatas = response.root;
  $scope.myDatas.data = [].concat($scope.myDatas.data);
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/UUWtDBK8qID1XoYeMXhu?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I would check if data is an array or not, and if not, just ammend the data to be an array:

Like this:

```
 $http.get("singledata.json")
.success(function(response) {
  if(response.root.data && !angular.isArray(response.root.data)){
    var object = response.root.data;
    response.root.data = [];
    response.root.data.push(object);
  }
  $scope.myDatas = response.root;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the whether the data is array or not. If not then you create the array as. Check this code its working.

For controller:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
$http.get("manydata.json")
.success(function(response) {
  var data = response.root.data;
  if(data.constructor === Array){
  $scope.myDatas = data;
  }else{
    $scope.myDatas = new Array(data);
  }
});
});
```

For html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in myDatas">

      Name: {{i.name}}
      Age: {{i.age}}

 </div>
```

Hope this helps.